# Does today() exist in vega-lite?

Tags: vega-lite

I'd like to show the difference between a date (Date1) from my data and "today" in my chart. I could add a column in my table that contains today's date, but I was wondering if I can somehow solve this in the transform [] statement to keep my tables lean.

Does something like:

```
today()
```

exist in vega-lite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `now()` function within the vega-expression; see https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#now

Here's a simple example of adding a column with today's date ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUkUG8IATAAwUC05AjDbQCrnlwtvkgC+ANAdMThlK9Og2at2Lbn3ACSFUqNLipkzlwC6vEFABOEAHZYAZgHs9AWzygAxqltoU8oYbMB3ABQBKEDxAQOEJQZpAAntya-pYQegDWJAAOZgCWhlB+IBiGtqFpAObwoAAeRSAmKRgoYCQh4ZlQKZYYAKqGKRlCYRixlmbpABaExP5QYYmCIBZgaagyIBEI5ZXVJMMNTa3tnQs9Vv1QQ-Kj45PTsyjcXFxAA)):

```json
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00"},
      {"date": "2021-01-01T00:00:00"},
      {"date": "2021-02-01T00:00:00"}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [{"calculate": "now()", "as": "today"}],
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "today", "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "date", "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate", "type": "ordinal"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Jake! Your example works well.I tried to use now() to define my scale, without success. I will post another question.